# Perl - Append to last line of a file (onto same line)

Tags: perl, append

Can someone let me know how to append an output file's last entry based on the current value?

E.g. I am generating an output `.txt` file, say:

```
a b c d 10
```

With some processing I get value `20` and now I want that value to be assigned and aligned with previous set, making it:

```
a b c d 10 20
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming the last line has no newline

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fd, ">>file.txt");
print $fd " 20";
```

If the last line already has a newline, the output will end up on the next line, i.e.

```
a b c d 10
 20
```

A longer version working in either case would be

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fd, "file.txt");
my $previous;
while (<$fd>) {
    print $previous if ($previous);
    $previous = $_;
}

chomp($previous);
print "$previous 20\n";
```

However, this version doesn't modify the original file.

Answer (score 6):

### Try doing this

*one-liner* version

```
perl -pe 'eof && do{chomp; print "$_ 20"; exit}' file.txt
```

script version

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;

 while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    if (eof) {
        chomp $_;
        print "$_ 20";
        exit;
    }
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

### Sample Output

```
$ cat file.txt
a b c d 08
a b c d 09
a b c d 10


$ perl -pe 'eof && do{chomp; print "$_ 20"; exit}' file.txt
a b c d 08
a b c d 09
a b c d 10 20
```

Answer (score 5):

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/$/ 20/' input.txt > output.txt
```

Explanation: Read the whole file by setting input record separator with `-0777`, perform a substitution on the data read that matches the file ending, or right before the last newline.

You can also use the `-i` switch to do in-place edit of the input file, but that method is risky, since it performs irreversible changes. It can be used with backup, e.g. `-i.bak`, but that backup is overwritten on multiple executions, so I usually recommend using shell redirection instead, as I did above.

Answer (score 1):

read the whole file first, you can do it by this subroutine `read_file`:

```
sub read_file {
    my ($file) = @_;
    return do {
        local $/;
        open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$!";
        <$fh>
    };
}

my $text = read_file($filename);
chomp $text;
print "$text 20\n";
```